# Calling child method from parent method

Tags: c++, inheritance

As the title states, I want to be able to print 101 in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class A {
    public:
        virtual int num();  // Method I want to override
        std::string str();
};

class B: public A {
    public:
        int num();
};

int A::num(){
    return 0;  // default value
}

std::string A::str(){
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << num();
    return s.str();
}

int B::num(){
    return 101;  // overriden value
}

int main(){
    B b;
    A a = b;  // Upcast
    std::cerr << a.str() << std::endl;  // Want to print 101, but print 0

    return 0;
}
```

In the general case, I have multiple subclasses of of a parent (`A`) that implement their own logic for calculating something (`num()`), and the parent performs the same stuff on the output of that something (`str()`) for all different implementations of `num()`. I couldn't figure out how to do this in c++.

I come from a python background and am still learning c++. Normally this would work in python, but if this isn't a good design or not the right OOP way of doing this, feel free to offer an alternative solution that doesn't involve inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a = b;  // Upcast
```

This doesn't do what you think -- it creates a brand new `A` object, initialized with the `A` subobject of `b`.

If you want to see `b` itself as an `A`, use a reference:

```
A &a = b;  // Upcast
```